# Javascript JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am using a get request from a server API and I am making a request and then doing this:

```
var resp = JSON.parse(response);
```

I call to the server providing 0001 & 0002 as arguments and
after the JSON.parse it returns an array such as:

```
{"0001":{"id":1},"0002":{"id":2}}
```

I know that traditionally if i were given static responses such as

```
{"placeID":{"id":1},"placeID":{"id":2}}
```

I could do this:

```
resp.placeId.id
```

but given that the return names aren't always the same how can I access that first value `resp.0001.id` given that `0001` may not always be the value returned?

Comment: If you use jquery then you can easily do it with `$.each(objec, function(key,value){...});`

Comment: Those are not arrays, they are objects and you need to [access them as such](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties).

Comment: You can always use `resp["0001"]`...

Comment: @Paul: Having two properties with the same name in an object literal is fine. The latter will just overwrite the former. It does "compile". In strict mode however it would indeed throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for...in` loop.

```
for(var property in resp) {
    console.log(property + ": " + resp[property]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the "0001" element of the response like this:
    resp["0001"].id
Since you say that you're providing the id in the query, you presumably have it stored in a variable somewhere.

If you really want to access the *first* element in the response, you can't use JSON.parse, because you'll lose the ordering information once you suck that data into an object. And if you have to care about the order of the elements, then that JSON is badly-formed, and should be using an array instead of a top-level object.